# Язык как деятельность

Tags: запрос-ссылок

Что представляет собой язык как деятельность и каковы аспекты анализа языка как деятельности?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком обширный, чтобы ответить на него в рамках вопроса-ответа. Вы можете прочитать об этом сами в Интернете.

Comment: @Серж Возможно, автор вопроса хотела поинтересоваться рекомендованной литературой, но не имеет привилегий создать метку. Я создал и добавил метку "запрос ссылок" по аналогии с "reference request" в других SE-форумах .

Comment: Да, действительно, я бы хотела понять, в каком направлении мне нужно двигаться, какие теоретические положения рассмотреть, чтобы разобраться в этом вопросе. Представленной в Интернете информацией я осталась не удовлетворена, так как она слишком разрозненна. Мне бы хотелось понять, какие могут быть опорные точки для ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: @grizzly, а как это работает?

Comment: @Серж Вариант ответа №1: в правилах указано, что если автор вопроса не имеет привилегий создать метку, он должен попросить об этом других участников. Вариант ответа №2: для создания метки нужно в поле "метка" ввести слово до 25 символов без пробелов. (Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, поэтому выдал наиболее вероятные версии ответов.)